# webrtc: always getting local video in remote video

Tags: webrtc

Below is my code with WebRTC for video chat. The problem is that I always get localStream in the remoteVideo element (in both peers), why is it so?

I don't have admin access to the host that I'm going to upload my website, so I should first use free STUN/TURN servers. I'm not sure if my iceServers usage is correct, is the problem with that?

I'm really sick of it! Any help is appreciated :)

```
$(function () {

var localVideo = document.getElementById('localVideo');
var remoteVideo = document.getElementById('remoteVideo');

var iceServers = {
    'iceServers': [
        { 'url': 'stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302' },
        { 'url': 'stun:stunserver.org' },
        { 'url': 'stun:stun.softjoys.com' },
        { 'url': 'stun:stun.voiparound.com' },
        { 'url': 'stun:stun.voipbuster.com' },
        { 'url': 'stun:stun.voipstunt.com' },
        { 'url': 'stun:stun.voxgratia.org' },
        { 'url': 'stun:stun.xten.com' },
        {
            'url': 'turn:numb.viagenie.ca',
            'credential': 'muazkh',
            'username': 'webrtc@live.com'
        },
        {
            'url': 'turn:192.158.29.39:3478?transport=udp',
            'credential': 'JZEOEt2V3Qb0y27GRntt2u2PAYA=',
            'username': '28224511:1379330808'
        },
        {
            'url': 'turn:192.158.29.39:3478?transport=tcp',
            'credential': 'JZEOEt2V3Qb0y27GRntt2u2PAYA=',
            'username': '28224511:1379330808'
        }
    ]};

var localStream, pc1, pc2;
var sdpConstraints = {
    'mandatory': {
        'OfferToReceiveAudio': true,
        'OfferToReceiveVideo': true
    }
};

getUserMedia({
    audio: true,
    video: true
}, gotLocalStream, function (error) {
    alert('error: ' + error.name);
});

$('button').click(function () {

    pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection(iceServers);
    pc1.onicecandidate = function (event) {
        if (event.candidate)
            pc2.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(event.candidate));
    };

    pc2 = new RTCPeerConnection(iceServers);
    pc2.onicecandidate = function (event) {
        if (event.candidate)
            pc1.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(event.candidate));
    };

    pc2.onaddstream = gotRemoteStream;

    pc1.addStream(localStream);

    pc1.createOffer(offer_success, offer_error);

});

function gotLocalStream(stream) {
    attachMediaStream(localVideo, stream);
    localStream = stream;
}

function gotRemoteStream(event) {
    attachMediaStream(remoteVideo, event.stream);
}

function offer_success(desc) {
    pc1.setLocalDescription(desc);
    pc2.setRemoteDescription(desc);

    //pc2.createAnswer(answer_success, answer_error, sdpConstraints);
    pc2.createAnswer(answer_success, answer_error);
}

function offer_error(error) {
    alert(error.toString());
}

function answer_success(desc) {
    pc2.setLocalDescription(desc);
    pc1.setRemoteDescription(desc);
}

function answer_error(error) {
    alert('error: ' + error.toString());
}

});
```

Comment: why do you have two peerconnection objects?

Comment: If you are wanting a connection between two different computers, you are going about it wrong. If you want to test a peerconnection so that the local video is set for both remote and local and displayed as such, then your code is just fine...which do you want?

Comment: I want to have it between two different computers on the internet. I though I should have two different peerConnections: one for the caller (the first computer which opens the page) and one for the callee (the second computer which opens the page). Is that wrong?

Comment: You are stuck into thinking that both individuals have to "access the same page." There should only be ONE peerconnection created, one page will be for the caller and the other for the callee. Your signaling server will handle who connects to whom. Which, you will need one to connect two different individuals. Web pages are STATELESS...

Comment: [Here is an example I wrote using SignalR and Asp.Net](https://github.com/Computician/SignalRWebRTCExample/tree/master/SignalRWebRTCExample). The logic for the peerconnections is rudimentary but should give you the idea of how to handle the signalling.

Comment: Actually, you have written your code twice; if your were to write them in a single page (which is my case) you would use two peerConnections. In face, I want to know what is wrong with my code.

Comment: I realize that, the logic for caller callee is essentially just one line that could be dynamically determined but that is just a quick example. Also, no, there is not a need for two peerconnections and it would break the logic of what a peerconnection is. You misunderstand the logic of a peerconnection. Whats wrong is that you are using two peerconnections. No application works this way(unless you are using different peerconnections for different types of media streams(data vs media).

Comment: Oh! yes. You are right @BenjaminTrent. Thank you very much. I have changed my code to something else which uses ASP.NET SignalR to communicate messages. I am still getting some errors there, though ;). I will post another question for that problem. I really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: You are very welcome! I am glad I got you going in the right direction :)